# Disk Quota questions

Tags: command-line, partitioning, permissions, fstab, quota

I have some problem when I'm trying to allocate disk limit for user in Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS system. I use edquota to specify the amount of disk space for user after edit fstab file. Here are some questions I'm confusing.

I have enabled disk quota in the "/" inside fstab file. The problem is when I use the command `sudo repquota -a`, you can see that the block size of my test2 user is 48928 KB

[image]

Let's compare the total amount of disk space of test2 user by issuing the command

```
sudo du -hc /home/test2
```

[image]

See what? The du command calculated the whole test2's home directory only 2MB. So why repquota calculates that much? 48MB.

By the way, How can I config the disk limit for user's home directory only? Is that useful? Because users only have permission of thier home directory. But I just want to know if it can be done.

Comment: Could you ask your last question in *another question*?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `du -hc /home/test2`, as you can see you don't have permission access at some files from `/home/test2`. Use:

```
sudo du -hc /home/test2
```

as you used for `repquota -a`.

Also, if you used `-h` (`--human-readable`) for `du` you should use `-s` (`--human-readable`) for `repquota`. See `man du` and `man repquota` for more info.

Comment: I edited! But just only 2MB after calculation. Still confusing very much X_X

Comment: @GeorgeLuong What about `sudo repquota -as`? If you used `-h` (`--human-readable`) for `du` you should use `-s` (`--human-readable`) for `repquota`. See `man du` and `man repquota` for more info.

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-wy2g3YlV1f0/Uh3hDoAFJ9I/AAAAAAAAM-M/NI96Een9Vq4/w791-h593-no/Ubuntu+Desktop+12.04+LTS-2013-08-28-18-36-26.png

Check this Radu

Comment: Hey! I found that, for example, If you put a 10MB file to the home folder of any user, the repquota will double that file's size! In this case, 20MB. 
But when I delete that file, empty the trash. rep only clear 10MB of the calculation... 
If you have time, you must check it down. The du command works fine. I tested.

Comment: @GeorgeLuong that sounds like a bug in repquota...